# Adding sconce lighting above window

Tags: electrical

As part of a kitchen renovation, the designer would like us to install sconce lights above the window over the sink. This is a load bearing exterior wall and there is a solid header across the top of the window, so I'm just not sure how to get the wires to the sconces.

I realize I can mount pancake boxes, but I'd have to cut a groove or something in the header to run the wires.

Any ideas for how I could safely wire up these sconces?

Comment: Ask the designer, Why a sconce instead of ceiling light?  Perhaps this is a good opportunity to explain to the designer what a header is and why you can not easily, if at all, put a sconce where one is.

Comment: Is surface raceway (often known as Wiremold(tm)) an option here?

Comment: Tell the designer to stuff it? Put a can light in the ceiling above instead of the sconce? Some cans come with deflectors to shine the light only where you want it, so it could be aimed at the wall above the sink instead of lighting directly into the sink (which, to be honest, sounds much more practical than lighting up the wall, but I'm not a designer, so what do I know).

Answer (score 2):

False wall that projects out beyond the header.  If the window is going to be surrounded by cabinets they won't even notice it.  A picture would help.